# Can I create venvs with virtualenv from a settings file?

Tags: python, virtualenv, config

Is there a way to write a "config" file for the creation of a virtual environment using the `virtualenv` module? For example something like this with a yaml-like syntax

```
python_version: "3.10"
path: "./venv"
requirement_file: "requirements.txt"
post_create:
    - python -c "print('hi from venv')"
```

Which creates a venv using python 3.10 in the directory ./venv, installs the requiremens from "requirements.txt" and then executres a python command "inside" the venv which prints "hi from venv".

Comment: There's an existing tool for this called [Tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/). It was designed for running tests for multiple versions of Python, but you can leverage that to do anything as it's simply an automation tool. It can run any command your system allows to run so it works outside the testing realm it's intended for. This tool would fit your use case as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once wrote a tool for exactly this purpose and have since published the source code [on my github](https://github.com/devds96/venvfromfile) as a package called "venvfromfile". I had polished it up a bit and also added some tests. It is currently not available on pypi and there is clearly a lot of room for improvements (for example, something like `post_create` is not implemented), but for my purposes this was enough. You can install it as described in the readme. I hope it is helpful.